# Wordpress rewrite get method url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I have now:

```
example.com/pagename/?id=15
```

What I want to have:

```
example.com/pagename/id/15
```

Is it possible to rewrite the URL in wordpress in this style?

Comment: You can just change permalink settings in WP for this.

Comment: @anubhava in settings I choose "post name", but when I try open url: `example.com/pagename/id/15` wordrpess redirect me to `index.php`